# Sampling from a 2d numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I was wondering if there was a reasonably efficient way of sampling from a 2d numpy array. If I have a generic array:

```
dims = (4,4)
test_array = np.arange(np.prod(dims)).reshape(*dims)
test_array
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Then I'd like to randomly set, say, two elements from it to a specific value (let's say 100). I've tried creating an indexing array and then applying that:

```
sample_from = np.random.randint(low=0, high=5, size=(2,2))
sample_from
array([[0, 2],
       [1, 1]])
```

But if I try using this to index, it gives me a slightly unexpected answer:

```
test_array[sample_from]
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]]])
```

What I would have expected (and the kind of result I'd like) is if I'd just entered the indexing array directly:

```
test_array[[0,2],[1,1]] = 100
test_array
```

giving:

```
array([[  0, 100,   2,   3],
       [  4,   5,   6,   7],
       [  8, 100,  10,  11],
       [ 12,  13,  14,  15]])
```

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.random.choice` + `np.unravel_index` to assign directly to your array.

```
test_array[
    np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(np.prod(dims), 2, replace=False), dims)
] = 100
```